# How does one map nested multi valued attributes?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

Let's say one has an Entity E.

- E has a multivalue Attribute M1 and a simple attribute A1.
- However M1 consists again of a multivalue Attribute M2 and a simple Attribute A2.

How would one map this diagram in case M1 is a PK and is not a PK?

Any help is welcome. I included the basic diagram below:

[image]

I expect something like:

**First Case:**

```
M1(Id[E], A1, Surrogate) 
M2(Value, Id[M1], A2) with A2, Id[m1], value being primary key
```

**Second case:**

```
E(Surrogate[M1], A1) 
temp(Surrogate) 
M2(Surrogat[temp], A2, Value)
```

I'm more interested in the logical design that the SQL / physical implementation.